# Use Inner Join and limit data repeat

Tags: php, mysql, join, inner-join

I Have these two tables:

[image]

[image]

The first one is `porttag` and second is `portfolio`. Basically, `porttag` are "Portfolio tags" where I associate the tags of portfolio items.

I want to get all Portfolio tables from `portfolio` filtred by `porttag` data.

I'm already using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM portfolio INNER JOIN porttag ON portfolio.id = porttag.port
```

But this return duplicated values, for example:

This return 1 item from Visibility tag and 2 items from Packaging tag.

I don't want to get duplicated items. Can you help me?

Comment: show your expected  result ..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to avoid producing duplicates. One is to use an inline view that returns unique values, and join to that. Another is to use an `EXISTS (correlated subquery)` pattern.

Another approach is to go ahead and produce the duplicates, but then collapse them with a `GROUP BY` clause. (I don't recommend this approach. I mention it only because it is an option.) To your existing query, you could add `GROUP BY portfolio.id`. But it would be indeterminate which row of `porttag` the columns would be populated from. (By default, a non-standard extension in MySQL will allow the query to run. Other databases would throw an error. And we can get MySQL to more closely conform to the standard, and throw an error by including ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode.) I don't recommend this approach.

**INLINE VIEW** example

The inline view `v` returns unique values of `port`, due to the `GROUP BY` clause. We use an aggregate (in this case `MIN()`) to pick out a tag value to return, when there are multiple tags.

```
 SELECT p.*
      , v.port
      , v.tag
   FROM ( SELECT t.port
               , MIN(t.tag) AS tag 
            FROM porttag t
           GROUP BY t.port
         ) v
    JOIN portfolio p
      ON p.id = v.port
```

This pattern meets the specification about regarding of using an inner join operation.

**EXISTS (correlated subquery)** example

If the "inner join" isn't a requirement, and if we don't need to return any columns from `porttag`, we can avoid a join operation...

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM portfolio p
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                  FROM porttag t 
                 WHERE t.port = p.id   -- related to outer row
              )
```

For every row returned by the outer query, the subquery following EXISTS is evaluated. If one or more rows is returned by the subquery, `EXISTS` evaluates to `TRUE`, and the row from the outer query is returned. If the subquery doesn't return any rows, then `EXISTS` evaluates to `FALSE`, which in this example, means the outer query won't return the row.

Comment: In the first version, perhaps use `GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag)` so you see all the tag names, not just the first one.